# .filter(v => !!v) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an application that can turns a tex file into a JavaScript object, with key-value pairs. The key being the word and the value being the number of times it has appeared in the text file. Let's go through it together:

```
FormatText.prototype.toDowncase = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.toLowerCase(); 
};
```

This turns the words to lowercase

```
FormatText.prototype.deleteWords = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.replace(/\W/g, " ");
};
```

This replaces all non-words with a space

```
FormatText.prototype.splitWords = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.split(/\s+/);
};
```

This turns the string in an array and splits at each delimiter

```
FormatText.prototype.filterEntries = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.filter(v => !!v);
};
```

**This one above I have no clue what it does.**

```
FormatText.prototype.countWords = function() {
  return this._data = this._data.reduce((dict, v) => {dict[v] = v in dict ? dict[v] + 1 : 1; return dict}, {});
}
```

**Could someone explain this one, however I will get it a try:**

This one takes the array and passed the method 'reduce' with two arguments. It counts how many times each individual word has appeared and returns an object with the 'key-value' pairs described at the beginning of this question.

Comment: `v => !!v` is essentially the `Boolean` function

Comment: `v => !!v` returns only those filter entries which are neither `0`, nor `""`, nor `false`, `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v => !!v` means take `v`, and coerce it to a Boolean type by applying NOT twice. So the filter function is basically removing any falsey values (0, null, undefined) from `this._data`.

`countWords` is counting the number of times each word occurs in `this._data` - it is going through the array and adding 1 to the count if the word has been encountered before, or returning 1 if the word has not been encountered before. It returns an object with the words as keys and the counts as values.

As a note, these functions change the type of `this._data`, from a string, to an array, to an object. That may cause bugs to appear if e.g. you run the same method twice

Answer (score 2):

Why not just return the value, without NOT NOT, like

```
v => v
```

because for filtering the value coerces to a boolean value.

From [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> ## Description
>
> `filter()` calls a provided `callback` function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which `callback` returns [a value that coerces to `true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values. Array elements which do not pass the `callback` test are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the double exclamation mark is useless: the value returned from the callback in **filter(*callback*)** is then coerced to a boolean automatically, so no need to do it using double exclamation mark. The following lines are equivalent:

```
.filter(v => !!v)
.filter(v => v)
.filter(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This one above I have no clue what it does.

The javascript operator **!** (logical not) performs a **type coercion** (to boolean) on its argument. So applied twice you somehow convert any type to a boolean value which gives you whether it is *falsy* or *truthy*.

This is interesting when you want to apply a condition to different types whose semantic is more or less "no value". For example:

```
!!('') //false
!!(0) //false
!!null //false
!!undefined //false
```

> Could someone explain this one, however I will get it a try

[reduce](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/reduce) is method of the array prototype which allows to iterate over a collection while aggregating value. 
In your specific example the aggregator is a dictionary which maps a word to a count (number of appearance). So if the word is not present in the dictionary it creates a key for this word with a counter initialized to 1 otherwise it increments the counter (if word already present).

A equivalent could be

```
const countWords = function (words = [], dictionary = {}) {

    if(words.length === 0) {
      return dictionary;
    } 

    const word = words.pop(); //remove and read the word at the end of the array
    if(word in dictionary) {//if key is present in the dictionary
       dictionary[word] += 1; // increment
    else {
       dictionary[word] = 1; // start a counter for new keyword
    }

    return countWords(words, dictionary);
}
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Seems pretty explicative.